# How to execute .cmd file within powershell script?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have cmd file, look like this

```
set Name=Joy
```

I want to execute that cmd file within my powershell script, then I want to see the value of cmd file from `command line` with command `echo %Name%` and It should show `Joy`.
But I can not figure it out, I tried this way, but its not working,

#### 1st Way

```
$File = Get-Command .\TEST.cmd
& .\TEST2.cmd
```

#### 2nd Way

```
Invoke-Expression ".\TEST.cmd"
```

#### 3rd Way

```
&.\TEST.cmd
```

Comment: What you're asking cannot be done, because the batch file will always be run in a different process, and can thus not modify the environment of the PowerShell process. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: If you add `echo %Name%` to your batch file you'll go some way to solving your question. BUT I agree completely with @AnsgarWiechers - please explain the actual problem you are trying to solve, not how you think you should solve it.